# Apache Storm - composing a bolt with another bolt

Tags: java, constructor, decorator, composition, apache-storm

I am using Apache Storm and I am wondering is it possible to compose a bolt with another bolt like this:

```
public class MyNewBolt extends BaseRichBolt {
    private MyOldBolt bolt; // MyOldBolt also extends BaseRichBolt

    public MyNewBolt(MyOldBolt bolt) {
        this.bolt = bolt;
    }

    @Override 
    public void prepare(Map map, TopologyContext topologyContext, OutputCollector outputCollector) {
        bolt.prepare(map, topologyContext, outputCollector);
        //Prepare other stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(Tuple tuple) {
        bolt.execute(tuple);
        bolt.someOtherMethod();
        //Do some other stuff
    }

    @Override
    public void declareOutputFields(OutputFieldsDeclarer outputFieldsDeclarer) {
        bolt.declareOutputFields(outputFieldsDeclarer);
    }
}
```

After this I would submit the bolt:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
                         .
                         .
                         .
    TopologyBuilder builder = new TopologyBuilder();
    BaseRichBolt bolt = new MyNewBolt(new MyOldBolt());
    builder.setBolt("bolt-id", bolt).someGrouping(....);
                         .
                         .
                         .
}
```

This works when I run it in local mode but would it actually work in remote mode? How does Storm treat bolt serialization-deserialization in this case? How many tasks are now created?

Comment: Have you tried this on a cluster? I agree with your suspicion that there may be some problems with creating the workers for "bolt-id" because of the way bolt is created, but the best way to know is just try it and see. I seem to recall some limitations related to dynamic class creation.

Comment: I didn't set up a real storm cluster. I am working in local (testing) mode and when I run my code it works (no errors or exceptions). Because I learned not to believe in simulations I was just wondering is this a legal thing to do on a real working storm cluster. For my project I only have to test my topology in local mode. So maybe the real question is does the local mode simulate a real cluster 100% accurately or are there some exceptions?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you take another approach (which coincidentally is the approach I use).  Instead of treating the bolt as a reusable class, factor the bolt's business logic out into a pure-Java class.  Then if you want to reuse that logic in another bolt, it's much easier to do so.

I'll also suggest that you factor all behavior related to a specific stream (knowledge of names, types and order of values in the tuple, etc.) out into another class.  The implementation of your bolt classes should be fairly minimal.

Comment: Yeah, I abandoned the approach I mentioned above because it didn't just look right and I haven't seen it in any storm-starter examples. Good advice about the "factoring out the behaviour of streams". I will try to do that.